How to join mutiple columns together using pandas
I have survey data that has the question in the first row and then the responses in the cells below it. Some of the questions had multiple responses that were spread across several columns. I want to combine the columns into one.
   Question 1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5
    answer       
                answer      
    answer      
                        answer    

   Question 1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5
    answer       
    answer      
    answer      
    answer 

If possible I want to be able to make it a loop so it goes through the whole data file and takes other questions similar and does the same thing.
This is what I've done so far.
import pandas as pd

file_path = '/content/Survey.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
df.head()

columns_to_combine = []
start_idx = None

for idx, value in enumerate(df.iloc[0]):
    if pd.notna(value):
        if start_idx is not None:
            columns_to_combine.append((start_idx, idx))
        start_idx = idx
if start_idx is not None:
    columns_to_combine.append((start_idx, len(df.columns)))


for start_idx, end_idx in columns_to_combine:
    for index, row in df.iloc[1:].iterrows():
        combined_value = ' '.join(str(row[col]) for col in df.columns[start_idx+1:end_idx] if pd.notna(row[col]))
        if pd.isna(row[df.columns[start_idx]]):
            df.at[index+1, df.columns[start_idx]] = combined_value

cols_to_drop = []
for start_idx, end_idx in columns_to_combine:
    cols_to_drop.extend(df.columns[start_idx+1:end_idx])
df = df.drop(columns=cols_to_drop)

output_file_path = '/updated_survey_data.xlsx'
df.to_excel(output_file_path, index=False)


The dataset has 90 columns.
Here is an example of the data:
    Ethnicity
    Chose all 
    that apply  Unnamed: 81 Unnamed: 82

0     Chinese         NaN         NaN
1     Korean          NaN         NaN
2         NaN         Filipino    NaN
3    Japanese         NaN         NaN
4         NaN         NaN        Japanese


How I want it, with columns 81 and 82 deleted completely
    Ethnicity
    Chose all 
    that apply  Unnamed: 81 Unnamed: 82

0    Chinese     
1    Korean  
2    Filipino
3    Japanese  
4    Japanese



Are the questions missing from this example data, or what?

@wjandrea no, i've added a photo example of the data.

Oh! Question 1 is standing in for a question? That's not the first row, that's the header. Please provide some more realistic example data. If you want tips, check out How to make good reproducible pandas examples.

Also, please don't post pictures of text. Post the text itself using the formatting tools like code formatting (print(df)) or table formatting (print(df.to_markdown()).

@wjandrea I made the necessary changes to my answer. Hopefully it makes my question clearer.
